# I am new to python and i can't find why this program is not working?

Tags: python

```
def snt(a1, b1): 
     snt0 = a1+b1
     return snt0
def mnt(a1, b1): 
     mnt0 = a1*b1
     return mnt0
print("Hello to my console program")
print("This is a basic sum multiplication calculator ")
i=1
while (i>0):
    clicky=input("For sum click on 1 for multiplcation click on 2: ")
    if clicky==1:
        a=int(input("enter a"))
        b=int(input("enter b"))
        f=snt(a,b)   
        print(a ,"+", b ,"=",f)
        input("Click to go out")
        break
   elif clicky==2:
        a=int(input("enter a"))
        b=int(input("enter b"))
        f=mnt(a,b) before
        print(a ,"*", b ,"=", f)
        input("Click to go out")
        break
   else:
        i += 1
```

I can't understand why it's not working i know something is wrong with the while loop but i can't find it.
Note: I"ve just started learning python !

Comment: _it's not working_ What does that mean? What errors?

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: it keep showing "For sum click on 1 for multiplcation click on 2: " even if i typed 1 or 2 .

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string, eg. `"1"`. you need to cast it to an integer for your comparison to work.

```
clicky = input(...)
clicky = int(clicky)
```

Comment: Does input always return a string ??

Comment: Yes, it is keyboard input, so it could be anything

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct Answer:

```
def snt(a1, b1):
     snt0 = a1+b1
     return snt0
def mnt(a1, b1): 
     mnt0 = a1*b1
     return mnt0
print("Hello to my console program")
print("This is a basic sum multiplication calculator ")
i=1
while (i > 0):
   clicky = input("For sum click on 1 for multiplcation click on 2: ")
   clicky = int(clicky)
   if clicky == 1:
        a = int(input("enter a: "))
        b = int(input("enter b: "))
        f = snt(a,b)   
        print(a ,"+", b ,"=",f)
        input("Click to go out")
        break
   elif clicky == 2:
        a = int(input("enter a: "))
        b = int(input("enter b: "))
        f = mnt(a,b)
        print(a ,"+", b ,"=", f)
        input("Click to go out")
        break
   else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: There is no need to convert `clicky` to an integer. You can just do `if clicky = "1"` and then the program won't throw an exception if you enter not a number.

Answer (score 0):

The input on the variable clicky requires a cast, as you did correctly later for the variables a and b.

```
def snt(a1, b1):
    snt0 = a1 + b1
    return snt0

def mnt(a1, b1):
    mnt0 = a1 * b1
    return mnt0


print("Hello to my console program")
print("This is a basic sum multiplication calculator ")
i = 1
while (i > 0):
    clicky = int(input("For sum click on 1 for multiplcation click on 2: "))
    if clicky == 1:
        a = int(input("enter a: "))
        b = int(input("enter b: "))
        f = snt(a, b)
        print(a, "+", b, "=", f)
        input("Click to go out")
        break
    elif clicky == 2:
        a = int(input("enter a: "))
        b = int(input("enter b: "))
        f = mnt(a, b)
        print(a, "*", b, "=", f)
        input("Click to go out")
        break
    else:
        i += 1
```

Next time, when you open a ticket please try to make some effort to clarify what it is not working, what it is the error or the unexpected behavior you get.